# Why does this function using IndexOf always return 0?

Tags: f#

I have this function that checks the number of occurrences of a pattern in a string. The problem is that is keeps returning 0 no matter the input. The most frustrating part is that it worked 2 min ago and I did not change anything.

```
let Counter (text : string) (pattern : string) =
    let mutable count = 0
    let mutable i = 0
    while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) <> false) do
        i <- i + pattern.Length
        count <- count + 1
    count
```

Comment: It works only if the pattern is at the very beginning of the input. e.g. `Counter "abc" "ab"` returns `1`

Comment: As this is F#, you should remove the C# tag

Comment: But at the time it was working as expected, it found all the occurrences, not just at the beginning - why? :/

Comment: @ThatGuy - No... no they are not... might as well throw the Java tag (and a few dozen others) on here with that logic.

Comment: Anyways, I just really want some to help me with this problem

Comment: I don't really know F# and I don't have a compiler handy, but how is `((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i))` ever going to evaluate to `false`?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, just about always, that is why the block in the loop is not entered and the function returns 0

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that it looks like you're trying to assign a new value to `i` inside the test in the `while` loop, but the `=` operator tests equality and does not perform assignment.  The `<-` assignment operator has return type `unit` (it does not return the assigned value), so the fix can't be as simple as replacing the call to `=` with a call to `<-`.

The most straightforward fix is probably to break that test out into a separate inner function:

```
let counter (text : string) (pattern : string) =
    let mutable i = 0
    let moveNext() =
        i <- text.IndexOf(pattern, i)
        i
    let mutable count = 0
    while (moveNext() >= 0) do
        i <- i + pattern.Length
        count <- count + 1
    count
```

However, note that this is not idiomatic F# code.  Instead, I'd write it like this:

```
let counter (text : string) (pattern : string) =
    let rec countFrom (i:int) total =
        match text.IndexOf(pattern, i) with
        | j when j >= 0 -> countFrom (j+pattern.Length) (total+1)
        | _ -> total
    countFrom 0 0
```

Comment: Well it is based on this https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-occurrence and man it just seems odd that I have to change the whole code when it worked earlier... Thanks though

Comment: @ThatGuy - F# is a different language from C#.  You cannot blindly copy C# code and expect it to work in F# (e.g. because the behavior of the assignment operator differs, as was a problem here).  Your original code could never have been right, but it did happen to work for consecutive copies of the pattern at the beginning of the string (e.g. looking for "abc" in "abcabcd"), so maybe you initially tested it on such a "lucky" example.

Comment: @ThatGuy You incorrectly translated the C# code. And it cannot be that it worked at first and then suddenly stopped working.